# Preserve trailing spaces in Access DAO SQL INSERT

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

Am using DAO to insert data into an Access database. When I concatenate fields, trailing spaces are removed. How can I insert data RETAINING trailing spaces?

For example, the following code strips trailing spaces of fields ref and name when creating column "mytext":

```
INSERT INTO mytest (ref, mytext) SELECT ref, ref + name + '/' FROM mytable
```

mytable is a FoxPro 2.5 table which I have linked. I am assuming the columns in the FoxPro table contain trailing spaces, as my data in FoxPro does not take up the full width of the fields AND in FoxPro when I run a REPLACE including the concatenate operator, trailing spaces DO appear:

```
REPLACE ALL mytext WITH ref + name
```

Columns "ref" and "name" are character fields of length 10. If ref = "S1" and name = "fred"
- the command run in FoxPro sets mytext to "S1" then 8 spaces then "fred" then 4 assumed spaces
- the DAO command run in VB6 sets mytext to "S1fred"

Comment: What does select ref, len(ref), [name], len([name]) from mytable give as a result?

Comment: Good idea rene, should have had it myself!
When ref = "S2", len(ref) = 2
When ref = "S", len(ref) = 1
etc etc
- even though the field ref has length 10

Comment: Got it, thanks to your ideas rene. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming [name] is 10...

Maybe adding spaces explictely will work

```
INSERT INTO mytest (ref, mytext) 
SELECT ref + space(10-len(ref)), 
       ref + [name] + space(20 - (len(ref)+len([name]) ) )+'/' 
FROM mytable
```

You have to maintain this query if the columnsizes of ref and/or name changes.
To be on the safeside use left(ref + space(10), 10). At least it won't break if your columnsizes chnages

Comment: Thanks rene, this works a treat. (note though that I said name was length 10).

Your answer crossed with another answer I got (so I deleted mine). Another way is to append 10 spaces at the end (with "+ SPACE(10)", then take the first 10 characters of this (with "left(ref+space(10), 10)".

Comment: That will work as well, although mine version would be a little (just a little) more gentle on memory...

Comment: @rene: Your version will fail if `ref` contains more than 10 chars. `LEFT(column + SPACE(N), N)` will rightpad+truncate more predictably.